# HighCharts with unknown number of multiple levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I want to implement a Pie Chart which series is **dynamic** and has **unknown** number of multiple levels. So drill down series will be set after Ajax call.

Does **HighCharts** library support this scenario?

If yes , how can I set the drill down option?

If not, what is your suggestion?

Comment: You just need to construct the json for each serie to have an id and set the drilldown to the respective id. You can find an example here http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/1061/.

Comment: It is supported. For dynamic drilldown in Highcharts you might also take a look at a [async drilldown](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/async/) example from [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.drilldown).